# I'm trying to create PDF's with Prawn, but I get: Prawn::Errors::UnrecognizedTableContent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, prawn

I'm following this railscasts #153, and I'm trying to add table data to prawn. I keep getting this error:

```
Prawn::Errors::UnrecognizedTableContent
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Watch out, since prawn will get confused if your table contains any nil or non string values. Try using the .to_s method.

**Example**

```
@report.data.to_s
```

Comment: What if I have an image?

Comment: Arslan Ali, what error are message are you getting? 
This error specifically refers to tabular data. 
Here's a list, on this page. 

https://gemfury.com/boardiq/ruby:prawn/-/content/lib/prawn/errors.rb

Comment: Every column value must be in string format